# How to view multiple log files as one file in unix/linux

Tags: unix, log-files

I was wondering if there is a convenient way in linux/unix to read multiple log files as one.

More specifically, I would like to view a sequence of log files (app.log, app.log.1 app.log.2, etc) as one big file using normal unix tools (vi, less, etc). When the EOF is read the tool will automatically move to the beginning of the next file.

During my work I have to analyze uat/prod logs to investigate and solve problems. The fact that I need to traverse many log files disturbs my work and causes delays.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use lists of files and file globbing to specify multiple files.

One big file:

```
cat file1 file2 anotherbunch* log[a-z] | less
```

A sequence of files (type :n to go to the next one):

```
less -e file1 file2 anotherbunch* log[a-z]
```

The `-e` switches to the next file automatically when the end of the current file is reached (twice) and exits when the end of the last file is reached (twice). To do that on the first time EOF is reached, use the `-E` option.

Comment: hey thanks! It works but the problem i have is that it orders the files alphabetically instead of numerically. For example, the list log.1, log.2, log.10 is sorted as log.1, log.10, log.2 and not as log.1, log.2, log.10. Is there any trick for this?!

Comment: @Kostas: If there are no spaces, etc., in the filenames, you could do something like `find . -maxdepth 1 -name "log.*" | sort -V | less` for "one big file" or for a sequence of files: `less $(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "log.*" | sort -V)`.

Comment: It seems that the "-V" parameter is not available on my machine. Here are the available options: -b -d -f -g -i -M -n -r -c -k -m -o -s -S -t -T -u -z.

Comment: This is what I have come up with: less -M -e allocation-engine.log allocation-engine.log.? allocation-engine.log.??. Its not the best solution but it will work for most cases! Thanks again!

Comment: @Kostas: This might work to sort your files numerically since your `sort` doesn't have `--version-sort` (`-V`): `find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "allocation-engine.log*" | while read -r file; do num="${file##*.}"; if [[ $num == ${file#*.} ]]; then num=''; fi; printf "%03d %s\n" "$num" "$file"; done | sort | cut -d ' ' -f2`

Answer (score 3):

[MultiTail](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/)